Using html2canvas , the screen capture is not taken
<template>
    <div class="print-preview-div1">
        Take screenshot of this div.
    </div>
    <div id="screenshotcanvas" class="screenshotcanvas">
        <canvas class="my_canvas_id slds-hide">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <img src={imgsrc} class="lightense"/>
    <button label="Take Screenshot" onclick={printDiv}> Take Screenshot</button>
</template>

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import HTML2CANVAS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/html2canvas';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class ScreenshotComponent extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        loadScript(this, HTML2CANVAS).then(() => {
            console.log('html2canvas loaded');
        });
    }

    imgsrc = '';
    printDiv() {
        this.imgsrc = '';
        HTML2CANVAS(this.template.querySelector('.print-preview-div'),{
            scale: "5",
            onrendered: (canvas)=> {
                //show image
                var myCanvas = this.template.querySelector('.my_canvas_id');
                var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                var img = new Image;
                img.onload = function(){
                    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,270,350); // Or at whatever offset you like
                };
                console.log('img >> ', canvas.toDataURL());
                img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
                this.imgsrc = img.src;
            }
        });
    }
}

I’m using the html2canvas library to capture a screenshot of a specific element on my webpage. However, I’m encountering an issue where the screen capture process is taking significantly longer than expected. I need help understanding why this is happening and how to resolve it.

Since this is an open-source library, have you checked the issues section in the repository?

Title of the question: "... screen capture is not taken". Text: "... capture process is taking significantly longer than expected". So does it always slowly work or does it not work? Also: In order to facilitate questions regarding 3rd party Javascript libs, I suggest to state the exact version of the library.
